# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java

My result set is too large. If its returning a huge data set which consumes memory, then it displaying `OutOfMemory` error in server. How can I handle this problem apart from increasing the heap size?

Comment: A resultset isn't normally entirely in memory at once. You're probably keeping what you read somewhere and here's the problem.

Comment: use option  -Xmx1024m to increase your heap space

Comment: @OmarMEBARKI "apart from inrease heap size"

Comment: can not you query with limit option? like in - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-select-query.htm ?

Answer (score 0):

Try don't put so many data per one time, use paginator or something like this.

Comment: When you correctly request a database, the resultset isn't entirely loaded, you may very well iterate over a huge database with small memory.

Answer (score 0):

Check your query for the resultset is correct/ optimised in the first place.
And in most databases you can restrict the number of rows returned anyway with something like

```
SELECT top(1000) * FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a paginator pattern: instead of getting everything at once, periodically get only partf of the data. For example, instead of getting 100 results, you can get 20 results 5 times: 0-19, then 20-39, then 40-59, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you can't load the entire resultset into memory .... then don't!  I can think of three alternatives, depending on the situation:

- Only read part of the resultset at a time; e.g. get it in "pages".
- Reduce the resultset as you read it; e.g. by extracting the fields you need, tabulating, or whatever.
- Restructure your query so that the data reduction can be done in the database.

If you provided more details of what the resultset contains and what you are doing with it, we may be able to offer concrete suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you can structure your query so that a single query can return everything you need then with result set streaming you can get the database to return results to you one row at a time. Your memory use is then drastically reduced at the expense of increased data traffic between your client software and the database. In my own company we find this very effective when working with result sets with millions of rows returned. This functionality is database dependant, for MySQL it is described at

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-implementation-notes.html